# Quarkus can't get remoteAddress client correct, only get remoteAddress server

Tags: java, spring, ip, native, quarkus

I can't get remoteAddress client. I use quarkus 1.13.6.Final build native image

```
@Context
    HttpServerRequest request;


    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext)
        throws IOException {
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        requestContext.setProperty(TIME_FIELD, time);
        log.info("remoteAddress: {}", request.remoteAddress());
        log.info("localAddress: {}", request.localAddress());
    }
```

remoteAddress: only get the server's ip not client'ip.
In my application.yaml I use proxy-address-forwarding and allow-forwarded or proxy.proxy-address-forwarding and proxy.allow-forwarded but all not working

```
http:
  port:
  host: 0.0.0.0
  cors:
    ~: true
    origins: "*"
  proxy-address-forwarding: true
  allow-forwarded: true
```

Thank you for your help. Sorry my English is not native language

Comment: Have you tried newer versions of Quarkus? 1.13 is very old at this point 